# Socket.io - Error : socket.packet is not a function

Tags: node.js, socket.io, emit

i'm trying to emit an event to all sockets, but i got an error that i don't understand.

The code is quite simple :

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    [...]

    socket.on('Security:ImOn', function() {
        var id = socket.id.split('#')[1];
        io.sockets.emit('Security:IsConnected', id);
    });

    [...]
});
```

This event just send an id to all socket so they know that this new socket is on.

The error i got when the system try to emit Security:IsConnected :

```
Missing error handler on `socket`. 
TypeError: socket.packet is not a function
at D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io-adapter\index.js:143:30
at Encoder.encode (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io-adapter\node_modules\socket.io-parser\index.js:135:5)
at Adapter.broadcast (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io-adapter\index.js:121:16)
at Namespace.emit (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:219:18)
at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-security\src\AuthenticationController.js:30:24)
at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
at Socket.onevent (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:335:8)
at Socket.onpacket (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:295:12)
at Client.ondecoded (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io\lib\client.js:193:14 
Missing error handler on `socket`. 
TypeError: socket.packet is not a function
at D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io-adapter\index.js:143:30
at Encoder.encode (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io-adapter\node_modules\socket.io-parser\index.js:135:5)
at Adapter.broadcast (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io-adapter\index.js:121:16)
at Namespace.emit (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:219:18)
at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-security\src\AuthenticationController.js:30:24)
at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
at Socket.onevent (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:335:8)
at Socket.onpacket (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:295:12)
at Client.ondecoded (D:\Projets\Ecafa\ecafa-server\node_modules\ecafa-socket\node_modules\socket.io\lib\client.js:193:14)
```

I don't understand why socket.io drag me this error, io.sockets.emit() is in the documentation.

Can someone help me ?

Thx in advance for help and advice !

Cafa

Comment: Maybe you change socket in `ecafa-security\src\AuthenticationController.js`

Comment: Nope, AuthenticationController contain the io code.

Comment: You're trying to emit to all clients but passing the id of 1 socket to the function, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, i want to say to all sockets that the ID of this socket is disconnected or connected.

Comment: The event Security:IsConnected is a part of the authentication process. At the begening i try to send an event called "Security:NewUserConnected" just before the event "Security:Authentication:Successfull". But, it's not working, it's like when i emit an event it's terminate the event socket.on('Security:Authenticate'). Sorry if i'm not clear :/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i solved the problem.

I don't fully understand the problem but it's working.

Here's what i understand :

1. My code wasn't fully organized. For now, i give full control of socket to my controller. Before, some promise can fire a event on socket.
2. My hierarchy of event wasn't fully organized too. Sometimes i was trying to fire multiple event in the same time. Now every event receive one order and can only fire one emit, that's all.

It's really complicated to organized well Events Socket, i think i have to be aware of every Call and response, and where i am in my event.

Sorry if my english is really bad, it's not my born language :-/

Hope it will help.

Cafa